# Segmentation fault: 11 ? C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, operator-overloading, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

Can you tell why does this generate segmentation error? Problem seems to occur when operator[] is called and when I don't call it, goes fine. operator[] is supposed to return a reference to the element with index i.. any help would be great..

```
//dynamic_array.cpp file

#include <iostream>

#include "dynamic_array.h"

using namespace std;

dynamic_array::dynamic_array() {

        int *array;
        array=new int[4];
        array[0]=3;
        size = 4;
        allocated_size = 5;         
}

dynamic_array::~dynamic_array() {
    delete [] array;
}

int dynamic_array::get_size(void) const {
    return size;
}

int dynamic_array::get_allocated_size(void) const {
    return allocated_size;

}

int& dynamic_array::operator[](unsigned int i) {
        return array[i];
       }
//test.cpp file

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "dynamic_array.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {
  dynamic_array a;

  cout << a[0];

}
 //dynamic_array.h file

 using namespace std;

 class dynamic_array {
 public:
      enum {
       BLOCK_SIZE = 5,
       SUBSCRIPT_RANGE_EXCEPTION = 1,
       MEMORY_EXCEPTION = 2,
   };

   dynamic_array();

   ~dynamic_array();

   int get_size(void) const;

   int get_allocated_size() const;

   int& operator[](unsigned int i);

   class exception {
       public:
           exception(int n0) { n = n0; };
           int n;
   };
  private:

   int *array; // pointer to dynamically allocated memory
   int allocated_size; // total number of elements in allocated memory
   int size; // number of active elements
   };
```

Comment: You are shadowing your member variable array in your constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local declaration

```
    int *array;
```

shadows the member `array`. So the following code uses the local variable, not the member. Hence the member is uninitialized.

---

Instead of creating your own dynamic array, use `std::vector`.

That's safer and more convenient.

---

In other news:

- The `get` prefix in e.g. `get_size` is a Java-ism.
  In C++ a `get` prefix has no advantage, and it makes the code less readable. For example, standard library containers have a `size` method, not a `get_size`.
- Using `void` as a formal argument declaration, as in `get_size(void)`, is a C-ism.
  In C it has the important effect of telling the compiler that there really are no arguments, as opposed to any arguments. In C++ `()` indicates that.
- Not having also a `const` version of `operator[]` is inconsistent with earlier use of `const`.
  Consistency is very important in programming. Our expectation, e.g. when maintaining code, is that it's consistent. Code that's inconsistent adds costly man-hours to maintenance.
- The `ALL UPPERCASE` identifiers for constants are a Java-ism.
  Java lacks a preprocessor, and inherited the all uppercase convention from early C, which lacked `const`. C++ has both `const` and a preprocessor. Having `const` there's generally no need to use `#define` for constants (as in early C), and having a preprocessor there's a good tecnical reason to not use all uppercase (it conflicts with the convention for macro names). In addition many/most programmers see all uppercase as shouting. It hurts.
- The class `exception` should better be derived from `std::exception`.
  Instead of inventing one's own exception class that can carry an error code, just use `std::system_error`. That's what it's for. Alternatively, derive a class from `std::runtime_error`, or use `std::runtime_error` directly.

Comment: this is part of a homework. i'm not supposed to use new concepts as vectors. any alternative?

Comment: delete the lime int *array; in your constructor

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your constructor

Go like this for the constructor:

```
dynamic_array::dynamic_array() {

    array = new int[4];
    array[0] = 3;
    size = 4;
    allocated_size = 5;
}
```

the problem is this additinal line of code in the constructor:

```
int *array;
```

In your constructor definition, you declared a new local pointer variable named **array** and you allocated memory for that.

But this variable is local to the constructor and it is not the one declared in your class as may be you believed.

Comment: Please read up on ["give a man a fish"](https://www.google.com/search?q=give+a+man+a+fish).

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf: I'm aware of what you mean. I added some additional help.